# Problems with ResultSet Nodes

Tags: java, resultset, jtree

Quick questions...

I'm trying to make a Dynamic JTree but I can't get to put every database I have into one single node for each one. This is my code so far:

```
jTree2 = new javax.swing.JTree();
try {
    String DSN = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";
    conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(DSN, user, password);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}
try {
    sentencia = conexion.createStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR2");
}
try {
    String hi = "";
    ResultSet rs1 = conexion.getMetaData().getCatalogs();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs1.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while (rs1.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
            hi = hi + rs1.getString(i) + ", ";
        }
        //for
        String sb = hi.substring(0, hi.length()-2);
        jTree2.setModel(new FileSystemModel(new File(sb)));
    }
}
catch(Exception ae) {
    System.out.println("ERROR3");
}
jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTree2);
```

And the result I get is this:

[image]

Every database is splitted by a "," but I want them to be on a single node for each one. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Databases", true);
while (rs1.next()) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode  node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString(i), true);
                parent.add(node);
            }
            jTree2.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(parent));
        }
```